# How to copy multiple files using xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pdf, sql-server-2012

I am able to copy single PDF file from SQL server to particular location. 
But how can I do that with multiple files?

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'BCP "SELECT PDF FROM [MEJAMES].[dbo].tblPolicyForms WHERE FormID = 20 " queryout "C:\Users\UserName\Docs\Folder\'+@FileName+'.pdf" -T -N'
```

I have a table with FormID, PDF,PDF_Filename

```
select  FormID,PDF,PDF_Filename
from    [dbo].[tblPolicyForms]
```

[image]

How can I loop through each FormID, extract PDF file and name it PDF_Filename.pdf ?

UPDATE:

For some reason it gives me an error:

```
CREATE TABLE #tblPolicyForms
(
    FormID INT NOT NULL
    ,PDF varbinary(max) NULL
    ,PDF_FIlename VARCHAR(max)
)


INSERT INTO #tblPolicyForms
SELECT  FormID,
        PDF,
        PDF_FileName
FROM    [dbo].[tblPolicyForms]
WHERE   FormID IN (19,20,21,22)
--select * from #tblPolicyForms

DECLARE @FormID varchar(4);
DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(200);

DECLARE FormID_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT
    FormID
    ,PDF_FIlename
FROM
  #tblPolicyForms
WHERE FormID IN (19,20,21,22)
--where whatever conditions you need to get the FormIDs you want to use


OPEN FormID_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM FormID_cursor
INTO @FormID, @FileName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'BCP "SELECT PDF FROM [DBname].[dbo].tblPolicyForms " queryout "C:\Users\UserName\Documents\ExportDir\'+@FileName+'" -T -N'


FETCH NEXT FROM FormID_cursor
INTO @FormID, @FileName

END

CLOSE FormID_cursor
DEALLOCATE FormID_cursor
```

[image]

Comment: Output your query data into a .bat or .cmd file, with one file's BCP info per line, and call that instead. Alternately, make the string you call xp_cmdshell with multiline, e.g.: `'BCP "SELECT PDF FROM [MEJAMES].[dbo].tblPolicyForms WHERE FormID = 20 " queryout "C:\Users\UserName\Docs\Folder\IL02708G.pdf" -T -N' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'BCP "SELECT PDF FROM [MEJAMES].[dbo].tblPolicyForms WHERE FormID = 22 " queryout "C:\Users\UserName\Docs\Folder\IL00034H.pdf" -T -N'`

Answer (score 0):

I went the cursor rout because this gives you the ability to define your output list by whatever you want

```
CREATE TABLE #tblPolicyForms
(
    FormID INT NOT NULL
    ,PDF TEXT NULL
    ,PDF_FIlename VARCHAR(200)
)


INSERT INTO #tblPolicyForms
    VALUES(18, 'skjdfsakdjfhsldkfhsdlkjfhsdkfjh', 'PDF18Name.pdf')
    ,(19, 'skjdfsakdjfhsldkfhsdlkjfhsdkfjh', 'PDF19Name.pdf')
    ,(20, 'skjdfsakdjfhsldkfhsdlkjfhsdkfjh', 'PDF20Name.pdf')
    ,(21, 'skjdfsakdjfhsldkfhsdlkjfhsdkfjh', 'PDF21Name.pdf')
    ,(22, 'skjdfsakdjfhsldkfhsdlkjfhsdkfjh', 'PDF22Name.pdf')
    ,(23, 'skjdfsakdjfhsldkfhsdlkjfhsdkfjh', 'PDF23Name.pdf')
    ,(24, 'skjdfsakdjfhsldkfhsdlkjfhsdkfjh', 'PDF24Name.pdf')
    ,(25, 'skjdfsakdjfhsldkfhsdlkjfhsdkfjh', 'PDF25Name.pdf')
    ,(26, 'skjdfsakdjfhsldkfhsdlkjfhsdkfjh', 'PDF26Name.pdf')
    ,(27, 'skjdfsakdjfhsldkfhsdlkjfhsdkfjh', 'PDF27Name.pdf')


DECLARE @FormID varchar(4);
DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(200);

DECLARE FormID_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT
    FormID
    ,PDF_FIlename
FROM
    #tblPolicyForms
--where whatever conditions you need to get the FormIDs you want to use


OPEN FormID_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM FormID_cursor
INTO @FormID, @FileName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'BCP "SELECT PDF FROM [MEJAMES].[dbo].tblPolicyForms WHERE FormID = '+@FormID+' " queryout "C:\Users\UserName\Docs\Folder\'+@FileName+'.pdf" -T -N'
--  SELECT 'BCP "SELECT PDF FROM [MEJAMES].[dbo].tblPolicyForms WHERE FormID = '+@FormID+' " queryout "C:\Users\UserName\Docs\Folder\'+@FileName+'.pdf" -T -N'

FETCH NEXT FROM FormID_cursor
INTO @FormID, @FileName

END

CLOSE FormID_cursor
DEALLOCATE FormID_cursor
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @FormID varchar(4);
DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(200);
DECLARE @CmdString VARCHAR(2000);

DECLARE FormID_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT
    FormID
    ,PDF_FIlename
FROM
    [dbo].[tblPolicyForms]
WHERE
    FormID IN (19,20,21,22)
--where whatever conditions you need to get the FormIDs you want to use


OPEN FormID_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM FormID_cursor
INTO @FormID, @FileName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    SET @CmdString = 'BCP "SELECT PDF FROM [dbo].[tblPolicyForms] where FormID = '+@FormID+' " queryout "C:\Users\UserName\Documents\ExportDir\'+@FileName+'" -T -N';
    EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @CmdString;

FETCH NEXT FROM FormID_cursor
INTO @FormID, @FileName

END

CLOSE FormID_cursor
DEALLOCATE FormID_cursor
```